# Cannot get parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hi I have the following problem:

I open an url in an iframe:

```
<iframe name="framenamex" id="frameidx" 

<a href="urlx.." target="framenamex">..xxx..
```

then I want to hide the iframe from the iframe:

```
<div onclick="javascript:parent.document.getElementById('frameidx').style.visibility='hidden'">
```

but it does not work, it seems like this frame has no parent, because when i call parent.location or window.top.location I get nothing.

please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they in the same domain?

Comment: Is Same Origin Policy being violated?